# How do I get rid of default opacity in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to draw 2 black lines in HTML5 canvas:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KFNt5/
Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height = 150;
canvas.width = 150;
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvasContext.beginPath();

// Draw the red line.
canvasContext.strokeStyle = '#000';
canvasContext.moveTo(10, 0);
canvasContext.lineTo(10, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

// Draw the green line.
canvasContext.moveTo(50, 0);
canvasContext.lineTo(50, 100);
canvasContext.stroke();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);​
```

However, the line to the right is gray, implying that it is semitransparent. How do I ensure that the default opacity is 100 (not transparent at all)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line is lighter due to anti-aliasing. You can include the following line to ensure that you render each line once and avoid the anti-aliasing effect.

```
canvasContext.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bagWQ/

Comment: Thank you, it works, but this is weird. How does translating by half a pixel in both directions turn off anti-aliasing?

Comment: It isn't actually turning off anti-aliasing. It just ensures that horizontal and vertical lines that are one pixel wide do not straddle pixel boundaries. Here's a good explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_lineWidth_example

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is darker because you drew it twice, once for each call to `stroke()`. The second call to `stroke()` draws both lines because you didn't start a new path.

Comment: True, but why does drawing black on black yield a darker hue? That implies there is a default transparency, right?

Comment: Indeed, as Greg Ross points out, I forgot to peer more closely at the image. I've recently switched to a high-resolution monitor and it's hard to tell whether a line is 1 or 2 pixels wide...